# Not giving desired output in python

Tags: python

this program is supposed to read an input file that has a category called year. So, if the user types 198, the output should give all the years having 198 in it e.g. 1981,1982,...etc.
But, the output is also picking up 199

```
Sierra Leone       WB_LI    0 Africa    1992
Sierra Leone       WB_LI    0 Africa    1993
Sierra Leone       WB_LI    0 Africa    1994
Sierra Leone       WB_LI    0 Africa    1995
Sierra Leone       WB_LI    0 Africa    1996
Sierra Leone       WB_LI    0 Africa    1997
```

Each line of the file contains the following fields, where there is one space between fields:
Country (50 characters)
Income Level (6 characters)
Percent Vaccinated (3 characters)
Region (25 characters)
Year (4 characters). So, altogether I have 92 characters and I am going through each characters from 88 on wards and matching them with characters in year to find the desired year. I think I probably have some error in my logic and that is also considering 199 as an instance. I am not supposed to use list or tuple. Just file.

Here is what i have done with my code:

```
def main():

    #checks if the input file exists or not.
    #If the file exists, then the program breaks out of the loop and
    #moves on. Otherwise, the program halts with an IOError message. 
    while True:
        try:
            input_file=open('measles.txt','r')
            break
        except IOError:
            print("Error opening file:",input_file)
            break

    f2=input("What is the name of the output file? ")

    #checks if the output file exists or not.
    #If the file exists, then the program breaks out of the loop and
    #moves on. Otherwise, the program halts with an IOError message. 
    while True:
        try:
            output_file=open(f2,'w')
            break
        except IOError:
            print("Error opening file:",output_file)
            break

    #for loop prints all lines of the input file to the output file.
 year=str(input('Input year: '))
    line=input_file.readline().strip()

    while line!="":
        for line in input_file:

            if year==line[88:92]:
                output_file.write(line)            
            elif year==line[88:91]:
                output_file.write(line)
            elif year==line[88:90]:
                output_file.write(line) 
            elif year==line[88:89]:
                output_file.write(line)            
            elif year.lower()=="all" or year=="''" or year=='""':
                print(line)

        line=input_file.readline().strip()


    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()

main()
```

Could anyone please take a look at my code and point out the problem? Thanks
Here is a few lines of the file that I am dealing with.

```
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   11 Eastern Mediterranean     1980
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI    0 Eastern Mediterranean     1981
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI    8 Eastern Mediterranean     1982
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI    9 Eastern Mediterranean     1983
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   14 Eastern Mediterranean     1984
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   14 Eastern Mediterranean     1985
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   14 Eastern Mediterranean     1986
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   31 Eastern Mediterranean     1987
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   34 Eastern Mediterranean     1988
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   22 Eastern Mediterranean     1989
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   20 Eastern Mediterranean     1990
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   19 Eastern Mediterranean     1991
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   22 Eastern Mediterranean     1992
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   25 Eastern Mediterranean     1993
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   40 Eastern Mediterranean     1994
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   41 Eastern Mediterranean     1995
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   42 Eastern Mediterranean     1996
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   38 Eastern Mediterranean     1997
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   31 Eastern Mediterranean     1998
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   31 Eastern Mediterranean     1999
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   27 Eastern Mediterranean     2000
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   37 Eastern Mediterranean     2001
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   35 Eastern Mediterranean     2002
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   39 Eastern Mediterranean     2003
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   48 Eastern Mediterranean     2004
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   50 Eastern Mediterranean     2005
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   53 Eastern Mediterranean     2006
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   55 Eastern Mediterranean     2007
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   59 Eastern Mediterranean     2008
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   60 Eastern Mediterranean     2009
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   62 Eastern Mediterranean     2010
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   65 Eastern Mediterranean     2011
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   68 Eastern Mediterranean     2012
Albania                                            WB_LMI  90 Europe                    1980
Albania                                            WB_LMI  90 Europe                    1981
Albania                                            WB_LMI  93 Europe                    1982
Albania                                            WB_LMI  96 Europe                    1983
Albania                                            WB_LMI  96 Europe                    1984
Albania                                            WB_LMI  96 Europe                    1985
Albania                                            WB_LMI  96 Europe                    1986
Albania                                            WB_LMI  96 Europe                    1987
Albania                                            WB_LMI  96 Europe                    1988
Albania                                            WB_LMI  96 Europe                    1989
Albania                                            WB_LMI  88 Europe                    1990
Albania                                            WB_LMI  80 Europe                    1991
Albania                                            WB_LMI  87 Europe                    1992
Albania                                            WB_LMI  76 Europe                    1993
Albania                                            WB_LMI  90 Europe                    1994
Albania                                            WB_LMI  91 Europe                    1995
Albania                                            WB_LMI  92 Europe                    1996
Albania                                            WB_LMI  95 Europe                    1997
Albania                                            WB_LMI  89 Europe                    1998
Albania                                            WB_LMI  85 Europe                    1999
Albania                                            WB_LMI  95 Europe                    2000
Albania                                            WB_LMI  95 Europe                    2001
Albania                                            WB_LMI  96 Europe                    2002
Albania                                            WB_LMI  93 Europe                    2003
```

Comment: Your input doesn't match what you say it does. The length of the line is only 44. That said, the FIRST thing I'd do is look at your input to make sure that's all correct. The SECOND thing I'd do is to see if there isn't some sort of input separator you could split on, rather than relying on field widths. If not, I'd start assigning variables as soon as possible.

Comment: I did some changes to the code and it is giving me the right output but not in the right format. Also, if I type year as an empty string like "", I should get the original input file copied to the output file and I don't know how to write my logic to include empty string.

Comment: I'll write something up shortly on how I'd do it

Comment: I don't know how to attach a file here. Otherwise, I would attach the input file on here for a better visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, the input you provided doesn't match your description thereof. Your code shows the `year` field starting at index `88`, but your provided input is only 44 characters long. I'd start there.

EDIT: here is how I would write your program, given you can't use any containers.

```
def filter_results(input_file, output_file, year):
    for line in input_file:
        if not line: continue # skips if the line is blank
        if year == '' or line[88:92].startswith(year) or year.lower() == 'all':
            output_file.write(line+"\n")

def main():
    year = input("Give me a year: ")

    try: infile = open('measles.txt','r')
    except IOError: print("Error opening file: measles.txt")

    try: outfile = open(input("Name of output file?"),'w')
    except IOError: print("Error opening output file")

    try: infile,outfile
    except NameError: raise IOError("One of the files could not be opened")

    filter_results(infile,outfile,year)

    outfile.close()
    infile.close()

main()
```

That said, I'd begin by reading in the file and writing it to a `dict`. Something like:

```
lines = list()
with open('path/to/input_file') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        lines.append(
            {"country":line[0:51].strip(),
            "income":line[52:58].strip(),
            "vaccinated":line[59:62].strip(),
            "region":line[63:88].strip(),
            "year":line[89:93].strip()}
        # I may have screwed up that string splicing -- do one and doublecheck
year = input("Enter a four-digit year (or part thereof): ")
filtered_list = [line for line in lines if line['year'].startswith(year)]
```

Also there are some problems in your existing code.

```
while True:
    try:
        input_file = open("measles.txt")
        break # ?
    except IOError:
        print("Error opening file:",input_file)
        break # ?
```

Why are we looping here if we're ALWAYS breaking after one iteration? Drop the `while True` and just `try:except` without the `break`s. If you need to halt the program on exception, then just do `except IOError: raise`

Comment: sorry, I can't use dict,list, and tuple. I am supposed to work with file only. I should have mentioned it earlier. I apologize. BTW, I haven't given any input. The only thing I have given is how my output looks like.

Comment: @cobra You ARE using a file only. You're taking the file and putting it into a `list` of `dict`s for easy reference. This assignment becomes unmaintainable code without some form of structure. You're still reading the file line for line. How do you even expect to return results if you can't build a list of the filtered results?! That's literally impossible.

Comment: We haven't done dictionary in the class yet. So, list, dict, tuples are out. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @cobra then you need to make your assignment COMPLETELY clear to me, because the way I understand it you have an input file whose specifications you gave, you take input from the user in the form of a 3-digit year prefix, and you write a function to return lines that are filtered by that prefix. That last part, returning a filtered result of multiple lines, is not actually possible without using some sort of data structure that can return MULTIPLE results.

Comment: @cobra as a bonus assignment: write something to stdout without using `print` or the `sys` module! ;)

Comment: I would just request you for one more thing. I am getting the output right. The only problem is formatting. I have already spend a considerable amount of time on this. At this point, it will be ok if I can just have one more condition in my code i.e. if someone types an empty string for year, the program should be able to return the original file. I tried several lines and for some reason, I am not getting them to work. I was wondering if you could give me some ideas in that direction.

Comment: @cobra I'm not berating you, I'm telling you that your requested output AS WRITTEN is impossible, so your assignment must not be what you described it to be. Can you re-write it in a way that's completely clear?

Comment: 1. The program in “proj06a.py” will copy selected lines from “measles.txt” into a file selected by the user. a) The program will always read from “measles.txt” (it will not prompt the user for the
name of the input file). If it is unable to open that file, the program will halt.

Comment: b) The program will prompt the user for the name of the output file. If that file does not exist, the program will create it and continue. If that file does exist, the program will discard the
current contents of the file and continue.

Comment: c) The program will prompt the user to enter a year, and will copy all lines of “measles.txt” selected by the user’s response. A line is selected if the user’s response matches the Year field or any of its prefixes. All lines are selected if the user’s response is any of the values in the set {“”, “all”, “ALL”}. Note that “” is the empty string.

Comment: For example, a line whose Year field contains “1987” would be selected by any of the following user responses: {“1”, “19”, “198”, “1987”, “”, “all”, “”ALL”}.

Comment: 2. The output file created by the program will have the same format as the input file (same field
widths and spacing). Note that when the user selects all lines, the output file will be identical to the input file.3. The program will display appropriate messages to inform the user about any unusual
circumstances.

Comment: I have posted the entire project here in several parts. Hope it makes sense and thanks a lot for working with me.

Comment: @cobra change your line `elif year=="all" or year=="ALL"` to include `or year == ''`

Comment: Your `if/elif` statements are a huge mess though. If `year` always starts with index 88, just do `if line[88:92].startswith(year)` and you can drop the rest of the `elif`s.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. The codes you are suggesting are new to me. But, I am learning some new things from you.So, thanks for that. I tried changing the year=='ALL' or year=='all' to year=='ALL' or year=='all' or year=="" and it gives me a blank output file.

Comment: @cobra I re-wrote with your structure, try it.

Comment: I tried your code and it is still giving me a blank output file when I am looking for a year=="".

Comment: I also have added few lines of my input file for your convenience.

Comment: +1. Anyone that's willing to deal with a cobra in programming class probably deserves a +10

Comment: @cobra make sure your `output_file` is closing. I can't replicate your issue with the data you gave me.

Comment: I just tried something weird. I just don't know if it is right or wrong. This is the code I used to make empty string work. year=='""' or year=="''": output_file.write(line) and the program is returning the original input file. Even if the code is working, I just think this is not the right way to do it. And, yes my output_file.close() line is at the end of the code. Thanks a lot for working with me. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Wait...were you giving it `''` for an input, or were you just passing it an empty string? You never specified how you were getting your `year` input....

Comment: In my code, I prompted `year = input("give me a year")`. If you run my code, when it gets there just press enter, don't enter two quotation marks. That's not an empty string, it's two quotation marks! :D

Comment: when it asked for year, I just typed "" with the previous code.

Comment: with the new code, I wrote year==' " " '(gave some space to make it clear. there shouldnt be any space). So, basically I made the empty string a string in the code. May be the program wasn't giving anything in the output file because empty string is not considered as a string.

Comment: oh BTW, i tried the new empty string code with my previous codes.

Comment: @cobra I think you need to do some basic deep thinking about what an `empty string` means. When you enter your year, you don't surround it with quotes (e.g. you don't enter `"198"` when it asks for a year, you just type `198`), but when the program interprets it, it is a string with value `"198"`. The empty string is `""` not because two quotation marks are some magic construction called the "Empty String," but because it is a string literal (denoted by two `"`s surrounding some text) with NOTHING BETWEEN THEM. If you want to test the empty string as input, WRITE NOTHING at the input prompt :)

Comment: Sorry again. While I was doing my editing, I probably deleted some lines from the code. I have done some editing and this time the whole code is there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It didn't occur to me at all and i wasn't even thinking about empty string as not typing anything at all. Now, the program is returning the original input file for typing nothing for year. Thanks again.